# jQuery live search - filter out HTML

Tags: jquery

I have a live search box running on a website, it all works and looks great, however when i type something in, then scroll down the list to make a selection, when i press enter, the HTML that makes the formatting of search list goes into the input box as whitespace.

Does anyone have any ideas on how i can filter this whitespace out?

**Search Box**

```
<div id="search">

 <form id="search-form" name="search-form" method="post" action="/search/">

  <input type="text" id="searchbox" name="searchbox" onkeyup="ajax_showOptions(this,'getCountriesByLetters',event)" value="" autocomplete="off" onblur="fill();" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit_search" name="finder-go" value="&nbsp;" />

 </form>

</div>
```

**livesearch.php**

```
    <?php
if(isset($_GET['getCountriesByLetters']) && isset($_GET['letters'])){


  $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shows` WHERE `artist` LIKE '".$_GET['letters']."%' OR `show_title` LIKE '".$_GET['letters']."%' LIMIT 10");

  while($inf = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

   $selectz = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shows` WHERE `artist` = '".$inf['artist']."'");
   $resultz = mysql_fetch_array($selectz);


    echo trim('<a href="/shows/'.$inf['uri'].'/">'.$inf['artist'].'</a>|');
  }

  $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `festivals` WHERE `name` LIKE '".$_GET['letters']."%' LIMIT 10");

  while($inf = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

   $selectz = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `festivals` WHERE `name` = '".$inf['name']."'");
   $resultz = mysql_fetch_array($selectz);


    echo '<div class="search-res">
      <a href="/festival/'.$resultz['uri'].'/"><img src="/image.php?filename=admin/uploads/shows/'.$resultz['image'].'&width=60&heigh=34" class="search-image" /></a>
      <p class="search-name"><a href="/festival/'.$resultz['uri'].'/" onClick="fill(\''.$result->artist.'\');"> > '.$inf['name'].'</a></p>
     </div>|';
  }

 }
?>
```

**live-search-ajax.js**

```
    function sack(file) {

 this.xmlhttp = null;



 this.resetData = function() {

  this.method = "POST";

    this.queryStringSeparator = "?";

  this.argumentSeparator = "&";

  this.URLString = "";

  this.encodeURIString = true;

    this.execute = false;

    this.element = null;

  this.elementObj = null;

  this.requestFile = file;

  this.vars = new Object();

  this.responseStatus = new Array(2);

   };



 this.resetFunctions = function() {

    this.onLoading = function() { };

    this.onLoaded = function() { };

    this.onInteractive = function() { };

    this.onCompletion = function() { };

    this.onError = function() { };

  this.onFail = function() { };

 };



 this.reset = function() {

  this.resetFunctions();

  this.resetData();

 };



 this.createAJAX = function() {

  try {

   this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

  } catch (e1) {

   try {

    this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

   } catch (e2) {

    this.xmlhttp = null;

   }

  }



  if (! this.xmlhttp) {

   if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {

    this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   } else {

    this.failed = true;

   }

  }

 };



 this.setVar = function(name, value){

  this.vars[name] = Array(value, false);

 };



 this.encVar = function(name, value, returnvars) {

  if (true == returnvars) {

   return Array(encodeURIComponent(name), encodeURIComponent(value));

  } else {

   this.vars[encodeURIComponent(name)] = Array(encodeURIComponent(value), true);

  }

 }



 this.processURLString = function(string, encode) {

  encoded = encodeURIComponent(this.argumentSeparator);

  regexp = new RegExp(this.argumentSeparator + "|" + encoded);

  varArray = string.split(regexp);

  for (i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++){

   urlVars = varArray[i].split("=");

   if (true == encode){

    this.encVar(urlVars[0], urlVars[1]);

   } else {

    this.setVar(urlVars[0], urlVars[1]);

   }

  }

 }



 this.createURLString = function(urlstring) {

  if (this.encodeURIString && this.URLString.length) {

   this.processURLString(this.URLString, true);

  }



  if (urlstring) {

   if (this.URLString.length) {

    this.URLString += this.argumentSeparator + urlstring;

   } else {

    this.URLString = urlstring;

   }

  }



  // prevents caching of URLString

  this.setVar("rndval", new Date().getTime());



  urlstringtemp = new Array();

  for (key in this.vars) {

   if (false == this.vars[key][1] && true == this.encodeURIString) {

    encoded = this.encVar(key, this.vars[key][0], true);

    delete this.vars[key];

    this.vars[encoded[0]] = Array(encoded[1], true);

    key = encoded[0];

   }



   urlstringtemp[urlstringtemp.length] = key + "=" + this.vars[key][0];

  }

  if (urlstring){

   this.URLString += this.argumentSeparator + urlstringtemp.join(this.argumentSeparator);

  } else {

   this.URLString += urlstringtemp.join(this.argumentSeparator);

  }

 }



 this.runResponse = function() {

  eval(this.response);

 }



 this.runAJAX = function(urlstring) {

  if (this.failed) {

   this.onFail();

  } else {

   this.createURLString(urlstring);

   if (this.element) {

    this.elementObj = document.getElementById(this.element);

   }

   if (this.xmlhttp) {

    var self = this;

    if (this.method == "GET") {

     totalurlstring = this.requestFile + this.queryStringSeparator + this.URLString;

     this.xmlhttp.open(this.method, totalurlstring, true);

    } else {

     this.xmlhttp.open(this.method, this.requestFile, true);

     try {

      this.xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

     } catch (e) { }

    }



    this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

     switch (self.xmlhttp.readyState) {

      case 1:

       self.onLoading();

       break;

      case 2:

       self.onLoaded();

       break;

      case 3:

       self.onInteractive();

       break;

      case 4:

       self.response = self.xmlhttp.responseText;

       self.responseXML = self.xmlhttp.responseXML;

       self.responseStatus[0] = self.xmlhttp.status;

       self.responseStatus[1] = self.xmlhttp.statusText;



       if (self.execute) {

        self.runResponse();

       }



       if (self.elementObj) {

        elemNodeName = self.elementObj.nodeName;

        elemNodeName.toLowerCase();

        if (elemNodeName == "input"

        || elemNodeName == "select"

        || elemNodeName == "option"

        || elemNodeName == "textarea") {

         self.elementObj.value = self.response;

        } else {

         self.elementObj.innerHTML = self.response;

        }

       }

       if (self.responseStatus[0] == "200") {

        self.onCompletion();

       } else {

        self.onError();

       }



       self.URLString = "";

       break;

     }

    };



    this.xmlhttp.send(this.URLString);

   }

  }

 };



 this.reset();

 this.createAJAX();

}

**live-search.js**

     var ajaxBox_offsetX = 0;

 var ajaxBox_offsetY = 0;

 var ajax_list_externalFile = 'inc/lib/livesearch.php'; // Path to external file

 var minimumLettersBeforeLookup = 1; // Number of letters entered before a lookup is performed.



 var ajax_list_objects = new Array();

 var ajax_list_cachedLists = new Array();

 var ajax_list_activeInput = false;

 var ajax_list_activeItem;

 var ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem = false;

 var ajax_list_currentLetters = new Array();

 var ajax_optionDiv = false;

 var ajax_optionDiv_iframe = false;



 var ajax_list_MSIE = false;

 if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')>=0 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera')<0)ajax_list_MSIE=true;



 var currentListIndex = 0;



 function ajax_getTopPos(inputObj)

 {



   var returnValue = inputObj.offsetTop;

   while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){

    returnValue += inputObj.offsetTop;

   }

   return returnValue;

 }

 function ajax_list_cancelEvent()

 {

  return false;

 }



 function ajax_getLeftPos(inputObj)

 {

   var returnValue = inputObj.offsetLeft;

   while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null)returnValue += inputObj.offsetLeft;



   return returnValue;

 }



 function ajax_option_setValue(e,inputObj)

 {

  if(!inputObj)inputObj=this;

  var tmpValue = inputObj.innerHTML;

  if(ajax_list_MSIE)tmpValue = inputObj.innerText;else tmpValue = inputObj.textContent;

  if(!tmpValue)tmpValue = inputObj.innerHTML;

  ajax_list_activeInput.value = tmpValue;

  if(document.getElementById(ajax_list_activeInput.name + '_hidden'))document.getElementById(ajax_list_activeInput.name + '_hidden').value = inputObj.id;



    //var f1=setTimeout('ajax_list_activeInput.focus()',1);

    //var f2=setTimeout('ajax_list_activeInput.value = ajax_list_activeInput.value',1);



  ajax_options_hide();

 }



 function ajax_options_hide()

 {

  if(ajax_optionDiv)ajax_optionDiv.style.display='none';

  if(ajax_optionDiv_iframe)ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.display='none';

 }



 function ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(item,fromKeyBoard)

 {

  if(ajax_list_activeItem)ajax_list_activeItem.className='optionDiv';

  item.className='optionDivSelected';

  ajax_list_activeItem = item;



  if(fromKeyBoard){

   if(ajax_list_activeItem.offsetTop>ajax_optionDiv.offsetHeight){

    ajax_optionDiv.scrollTop = ajax_list_activeItem.offsetTop - ajax_optionDiv.offsetHeight + ajax_list_activeItem.offsetHeight + 2 ;

   }

   if(ajax_list_activeItem.offsetTop<ajax_optionDiv.scrollTop)

   {

    ajax_optionDiv.scrollTop = 0;

   }

  }

 }



 function ajax_option_list_buildList(letters,paramToExternalFile)

 {



  ajax_optionDiv.innerHTML = '';

  ajax_list_activeItem = false;

  if(ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()].length<=1){

   ajax_options_hide();

   return;

  }







  ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem = false;

  var optionsAdded = false;

  for(var no=0;no<ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()].length;no++){

   if(ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()][no].length==0)continue;

   optionsAdded = true;

   var div = document.createElement('DIV');

   var items = ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()][no].split(/###/gi);



   if(ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()].length==1 && ajax_list_activeInput.value == items[0]){

    ajax_options_hide();

    return;

   }





   div.innerHTML = items[items.length-1];

   div.id = items[0];

   div.className='optionDiv';

   div.onmouseover = function(){ ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(this,false) }

   div.onclick = ajax_option_setValue;

   if(!ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem)ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem = div;

   ajax_optionDiv.appendChild(div);

  }

  if(optionsAdded){

   ajax_optionDiv.style.display='block';

   if(ajax_optionDiv_iframe)ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.display='';

   ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem,true);

  }



 }



 function ajax_option_list_showContent(ajaxIndex,inputObj,paramToExternalFile,whichIndex)

 {

  if(whichIndex!=currentListIndex)return;

  var letters = inputObj.value;

  var content = ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex].response;

  var elements = content.split('|');

  ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()] = elements;

  ajax_option_list_buildList(letters,paramToExternalFile);



 }



 function ajax_option_resize(inputObj)

 {

  ajax_optionDiv.style.top = (ajax_getTopPos(inputObj) + inputObj.offsetHeight + ajaxBox_offsetY) + 'px';

  ajax_optionDiv.style.left = (ajax_getLeftPos(inputObj) + ajaxBox_offsetX) + 'px';

  if(ajax_optionDiv_iframe){

   ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.left = ajax_optionDiv.style.left;

   ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.top = ajax_optionDiv.style.top;

  }



 }



 function ajax_showOptions(inputObj,paramToExternalFile,e)

 {

  if(e.keyCode==13 || e.keyCode==9)return;

  if(ajax_list_currentLetters[inputObj.name]==inputObj.value)return;

  if(!ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile])ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile] = new Array();

  ajax_list_currentLetters[inputObj.name] = inputObj.value;

  if(!ajax_optionDiv){

   ajax_optionDiv = document.createElement('DIV');

   ajax_optionDiv.id = 'ajax_listOfOptions';

   document.body.appendChild(ajax_optionDiv);



   if(ajax_list_MSIE){

    ajax_optionDiv_iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');

    ajax_optionDiv_iframe.border='0';

    ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.width = ajax_optionDiv.clientWidth + 'px';

    ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.height = ajax_optionDiv.clientHeight + 'px';

    ajax_optionDiv_iframe.id = 'ajax_listOfOptions_iframe';



    document.body.appendChild(ajax_optionDiv_iframe);

   }



   var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');

   for(var no=0;no<allInputs.length;no++){

    if(!allInputs[no].onkeyup)allInputs[no].onfocus = ajax_options_hide;

   }

   var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName('SELECT');

   for(var no=0;no<allSelects.length;no++){

    allSelects[no].onfocus = ajax_options_hide;

   }



   var oldonkeydown=document.body.onkeydown;

   if(typeof oldonkeydown!='function'){

    document.body.onkeydown=ajax_option_keyNavigation;

   }else{

    document.body.onkeydown=function(){

     oldonkeydown();

    ajax_option_keyNavigation() ;}

   }

   var oldonresize=document.body.onresize;

   if(typeof oldonresize!='function'){

    document.body.onresize=function() {ajax_option_resize(inputObj); };

   }else{

    document.body.onresize=function(){oldonresize();

    ajax_option_resize(inputObj) ;}

   }



  }



  if(inputObj.value.length<minimumLettersBeforeLookup){

   ajax_options_hide();

   return;

  }





  ajax_optionDiv.style.top = (ajax_getTopPos(inputObj) + inputObj.offsetHeight + ajaxBox_offsetY) + 'px';

  ajax_optionDiv.style.left = (ajax_getLeftPos(inputObj) + ajaxBox_offsetX) + 'px';

  if(ajax_optionDiv_iframe){

   ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.left = ajax_optionDiv.style.left;

   ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.top = ajax_optionDiv.style.top;

  }



  ajax_list_activeInput = inputObj;

  ajax_optionDiv.onselectstart =  ajax_list_cancelEvent;

  currentListIndex++;

  if(ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][inputObj.value.toLowerCase()]){

   ajax_option_list_buildList(inputObj.value,paramToExternalFile,currentListIndex);

  }else{

   var tmpIndex=currentListIndex/1;

   ajax_optionDiv.innerHTML = '';

   var ajaxIndex = ajax_list_objects.length;

   ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex] = new sack();

   var url = ajax_list_externalFile + '?' + paramToExternalFile + '=1&letters=' + inputObj.value.replace(" ","+");

   ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex].requestFile = url; // Specifying which file to get

   ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex].onCompletion = function(){ ajax_option_list_showContent(ajaxIndex,inputObj,paramToExternalFile,tmpIndex); }; // Specify function that will be executed after file has been found

   ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex].runAJAX();  // Execute AJAX function

  }





 }



 function ajax_option_keyNavigation(e)

 {

  if(document.all)e = event;



  if(!ajax_optionDiv)return;

  if(ajax_optionDiv.style.display=='none')return;



  if(e.keyCode==38){ // Up arrow

   if(!ajax_list_activeItem)return;

   if(ajax_list_activeItem && !ajax_list_activeItem.previousSibling)return;

   ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(ajax_list_activeItem.previousSibling,true);

  }



  if(e.keyCode==40){ // Down arrow

   if(!ajax_list_activeItem){

    ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem,true);

   }else{

    if(!ajax_list_activeItem.nextSibling)return;

    ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(ajax_list_activeItem.nextSibling,true);

   }

  }



  if(e.keyCode==13 || e.keyCode==9){ // Enter key or tab key

   if(ajax_list_activeItem && ajax_list_activeItem.className=='optionDivSelected')ajax_option_setValue(false,ajax_list_activeItem);

   if(e.keyCode==13)return false; else return true;

  }

  if(e.keyCode==27){ // Escape key

   ajax_options_hide();

  }

 }





 document.documentElement.onclick = autoHideList;



 function autoHideList(e)

 {

  if(document.all)e = event;



  if (e.target) source = e.target;

   else if (e.srcElement) source = e.srcElement;

   if (source.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug

    source = source.parentNode;

  if(source.tagName.toLowerCase()!='input' && source.tagName.toLowerCase()!='textarea')ajax_options_hide();



 }
```

**Search While Typing**

[alt text http://img.p4ul.me/sjgsce.png](http://img.p4ul.me/sjgsce.png)

**White Space When Press Enter**

[alt text http://img.p4ul.me/c9kbo9.png](http://img.p4ul.me/c9kbo9.png)

You can only see a little bit of whitespace there, but there is quite alot.
the site is: www.allthefestivals.com
search on the right hand side.

Any advice would be great thanks :)

Comment: Holy crap, longest question I've ever seen, kudos

Comment: yea sorry about that :( thought it would be wise to share the code for a better answer.

Comment: Future tip - The 1s and 0s button on the editor...select your code block and hit that to space it over 4 spaces so it becomes a code block in markdown, quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Man, that is a lot of code to sort through.  If you could narrow down your question a bit, I'm sure you would get better answers than this one.

From just looking at your results, it appears there is extra white space in front of what you are plugging into the input text, as well as an extra right-angle-bracket prefixing it from your php code.  I can't tell for sure without parsing a lot of your code out, but could it be that you simply need to trim off whitespace before inserting the name (s.trim)?

If it's not whitespace, then most likely you are either replacing the input with with another element (div, etc), or you have a css that is pushing it over to the right, possibly being copied when you do the javascript insertion.